# str_replace in a file doesn't work

Tags: php

I am trying to delete the html and body tags in an html file using preg_replace but instead of replacing the desired tags, the entire html file goes blank. I don't understand where I am going wrong...I feel I am going wrong at a basic idea but can't understand where
This is the code I am using:

```
$f = fopen ("game1/game.html", "w");
$replacetags=array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>','<head>','</head>')
$file=  str_replace( $replacetags,'',$f);
fclose($f);
```

Also if anyone could suggest a better method for deleting the tags it wd be helpful....
Thanks..

Comment: try looking at [striptags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), except you must *whitelist* the tags you want to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str_replace is not going to work with fopen handler (as i see on php ref), so you need to use this

```
      $replacetags=array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>','<head>','</head>'); 
      $file=  str_replace( $replacetags,'',file_get_contents("game1/game.html"));
      $f = fopen ("game1/game.html", "w");
      fwrite($f,$file);
      fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 3):

What you get as the output is correct. Where you have gone wrong is when you replace these tags `'<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>','<head>','</head>'` browser can n't render it as a normal web page. To be shown in the browser you should follow the correct formatting.

It should have the below format to be shown in the broswer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

For your infomation

[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string. You might want to look at that too.

Answer (score 1):

The `fopen` function opens a *file handle* (which is a `resource` type).

You probably want to use the [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) functions. They actually read and write data to a file.

Answer (score 1):

When you eliminate important tag as **body**, **head** and **html**, you are not able to see output in a browser.

Therefore, **str_replace** is working well.You can cross-check it by running following code:

```
<?php
   $f =file_get_contents('game1/game.html');
   $replacetags=array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>','<head>','</head>')  ;           
   $file=  str_replace( $replacetags,"",$f);

   file_put_contents("output.html", $file);
?>
```

After running or loading the page(that contains above source code) in a browser,When you open generated `output.html` file with text-editor, you won't see body, head and html tag.

UPD:
**Why HTML file goes completely blank**?

When you open files or URL with **[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)** in a **W** mode, following happens:

```
'w':  Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the
 beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length.
 If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
```

As you were opening file with **fopen** as `fopen ("game1/game.html", "w");` , the file pointer is placed at the beginning of the file and  file is truncated to zero length(**blank**), since you were not writing any content in game.html, thus the html file becomes blank.

**Also note**: The third parameter in **[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)** is `the string or array being searched and replaced on, otherwise known as the haystack`. But in your code, the third parameter **$f** that  you are passing is a file handle. As a result when you output `$file` string using `echo or print`, then **Resource id #x** will be printed instead of filtered(targeted ) string.

Comment: and I must add I wasn't seeing the output in a browser. I was seeing it in gedit... Even now I can't understand why the file went totally blank....anyway the problem is solved...

Answer (score 0):

The fopen should be:

```
$file = fopen('game.html', 'w+');
```

your game.html page got deleted with your code. See if not beleive me

also i will recommend you to work with `str_ireplace`.